# Функция javascript позволяющея пользователю менять размер div

Tags: jquery, javascript

Здравствуйте, может кто знает и может объяснить. У меня есть div contener с помощью jQuery делаю выборку и делаю этот элемент растягиваемым $( "#contener" ).resizable. но хотелось бы чтобы пользователь мог руками задать нужный размер. Например вбивает руками в поле ширина 1024px? а в поле высота 900px и div контейнер принимает эти размеры. Помогите люди добрые?

Comment: это ты конструктор сайта какой-то делаешь?

Comment: типо того. Случайно не знаеш ответа на мой вопрос?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот [простой вариант](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/UJ5fR/). Модифицируйте по своему усмотрению. Или [взаимосвязанный вариант](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/UJ5fR/1/), где при растягивании элемента, его размеры отображаются в полях для ручной уставновки.

Comment: Огромное спасибо

Comment: Здравствуте, Вы случано не знаете ответ на вопрос http://hashcode.ru/questions/238265/javascript-%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%B7-droppable